# How do I control which tabs a block is displayed in?

Tags: views, 8, users, blocks

Drupal 8.8.1 with commerce 2 installed.

Goal is to make better use of the ‘logged-in user’ landing page(My Account) by adding blocks of useful content.

Blocks created using the UI as well as coded blocks, which are placed into the Content region via *structure>block layout>place block*, all show up in the My Account user landing page, **no problem**.

However, the blocks also show up in each of the tabs added by commerce 2, eg Payment Methods and Orders(a list of the logged-in user’s orders), **and any additional tabs(My New Tab) which I add from code.** (So, it’s not a commerce2 issue).

In block layout, I have set Role Restriction to Authenticated Users, and Page Restriction is /user/* .

So, I’m obviously missing something about how to constrain the display of blocks in tabs.

How do I constrain my blocks display to only show up as required on a subset of the tabs on the 'My Account' user landing page?

Thanks.

Comment: `user/*` will match anything under the user/ path. You may want to try using `user/*/view` to get the My Account page, that may work.

Comment: Tried that. If Page Restriction is set to /user/*/view, the block does not show up on any tab. Other ideas? thx for replying

Comment: Tabs have a path. You'll have to add the path for the tabs as well.

Comment: Thx for ideas. I was fixated on finding a coding solution, but the solution was in theme. Add a new ‘logged-in user ‘ region, add page- -user twig template to display the new region, drop the blocks into the new region and set their visibility to negate the user tab paths where I don’t want the blocks to display. Drupal is so flexible, solutions come from unexpected directions.